# Silent remote java install in windows on multiple servers

Tags: java, installation, silent

Can anybody pls help me in achieving this task,

my requirement is to silently remote install JAVA on 20 different windows servers in a specific directory.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Installing Java is not a task, because you can not install Java - you can install a Java Virtual Machine which is able to execute Java code.

Comment: Hi Smutje, Thank you for the comment. I meant not literally as a task. I intend to install JAVA from the jdk-6u45-windows-x64.exe remotely from an admin box using a bat script. I am not so good in bat scripts and psexec and hence this request.